# Connection string in BIML

Tags: ssis, biml

I'm new to BIML, and are trying to connect to a SQL Server (2017) using biml (And visual studio 2017) using a username and password. Hoverer every time I try to connect the connection goes offline, and does not work. Not even if I set to online afterwards.

I've tried to connect using SSID, and everything works just fine the problem only occurs when it comes to providing "User Id" and "Password"

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">

<Connections>
        <Connection  Name="test_name" ConnectionString="Data Source=abc15\un1;Initial Catalog=extract;Persist Security Info=True;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;User ID=biml_user;Password=biml_password;" CreateInProject="true"/>
</Connections>*

  <Packages>
    <Package Name="test_name" ConstraintMode="Parallel" ProtectionLevel="DontSaveSensitive">
      <Tasks>
        <ExecuteSQL Name="Test Select" ConnectionName="test_name">
          <DirectInput>Select 1 As One</DirectInput>
        </ExecuteSQL>
      </Tasks>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Error message: *Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'biml_user'.".*

Do you need any other information?

/Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You have `ProtectionLevel="DontSaveSensitive"` set in your Biml, which will output an SSIS package that will not - as the name suggests - save sensitive information such as usernames and passwords.

You need to either change your Protection Level or persist your credentials in SSIS Parameters.

Comment: Hi @iamdave I've looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/security/access-control-for-sensitive-data-in-packages?view=sql-server-2014, and tried the diffrent security levels, especially EncryptSensitiveWithPassword, however I still have the same problem. Can you help me with an example or link to a good example (With the prefered security level)?

Comment: I would recommend you leave the solution as `DontSaveSensitive` and hardcode the connection details into some project parameters that you specify in your Biml.  You can then remove the values as stored in your parameters once your development is complete.  When you come to deploy the solution, you can then use parameters saved within an Environment collection to securely store and use the appropriate usernames and passwords.

Comment: Hi again @iamdave. I've tried for some time now getting it to work, but haven't. Can you create an example for me using the ProtectionLevel="DontSaveSensitive", usernam and password in the connection string AND the proejct parameters?

Comment: Apologies, but SO is not a code writing service.  You should find everything you need here: http://bimlscript.com/snippet/Details/102  --  All you need to do is parameterise your connection in the same way you parameterise any other SSIS object using expressions that reference your parameters per the example in that link